# validation with two diffrent objects but same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So i have this model Appointment:

```
validates :purpose, :extra, :appointment_date, :appointment_time, presence: true
```

and now this is situation: i want to get error if someone will want to make appointment in the same day and the same time. So i have to compare two objects of the same class and i have no idea how i can do it.

only one thing comes into my mind

```
def allready_booked?
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id]) <----- this is the part i dont know how to do it
  @appointments = Appointment.where(appointment_date: appointment_date).where(employee_id: employee.id)
  @appoitnments.each do |appo|
    if(appo.appointment_date == appointment_date)
      errors.add(:appoitnemnt_date, "is already booked")
    end
  end
end
```

And yes employee_id is in Appointment model

Comment: Have you considered using a PORO Service Class? Seems like a good use case for one.

Comment: i will consider it tomorrow maybe another answer will come out but thanks anyway!

Comment: You can try validating the uniqueness by passing an scope `validates :appointment_date, uniqueness: { scope: :appointment_time }`

Comment: @SebastianPalma - That won't allow *any* appointments on the same date/time, correct? Perhaps add `employee_id` to the uniqueness scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a model validation like so

```
 class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :available_time

    private
    def available_time
      other_appointments = Appointment.where(
                             appointment_date: self.appointment_date,
                             appointment_time: self.appointment_time,
                             employee_id: self.employee_id
                           ) 
      unless other_appointments.empty?
        [:appointment_date,:appointment_time].each do |attr|
          errors.add(attr,"is not available")
        end
      end       
    end
 end
```

Obviously if your appointments have a time frame e.g. 30 minutes you would need to alter this as it will only check against exact matches.

Also exact matches can be handled but uniqueness checking as mentioned by @SebastianPalma like so

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :appointment_date, uniqueness: {scope: [:employee_id,:appointment_time] }
  # Or 
  validates :appointment_time, uniqueness: {scope: [:employee_id, :appointment_date] } 
end
```

The first will add the error to `appointment_date` the second to `appointment_time` or both adds both (but will run multiple queries so better to write your own or pick one field to considered invalid)

Comment: First solution is interesting i will have to save it somewhere but the second solution works like a charm! I have set time to be like this: 7:30 - 8:00 - 8:30 - ..... - 14:00 and it works just fine. Thx for the answer!